# What is wrong with my jquery code for cancelling a href?

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/W59sw/3/

When someone clicks on the button, I want to prevent the page from redirecting, and do some custom stuff. What am I doing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W59sw/7/ fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include jQuery in your jsFiddle. There is nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You loaded MooTools and not jQuery on the jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You need to select jQuery on the left, not MooTools.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, but your jsFiddle is not loading jQuery. Also note that in this case you probably don't need to preventDefault() and should just use `return: false;`